# Image Normalization for CNN

Tags: image-processing, normalization, denormalized

I have seen multiple ways to normalize images before training them for a CNN.  One way I am thinking of going with is:

```
normalized = (gray - np.min(gray)) / (np.max(gray) - np.min(gray))
```

Is there an advantage to this approach vs the standard deviation approach?  Can the normalized image be returned to its original grayscale version (denormalized)?

Comment: it depends what you want. if you only want to have your data in the same range then rescaling is sufficient.  if you want it to have zero mean and unit variance you'll have to standardize it. maybe googling "feature scaling" helps?  you cannot "denormalize" an image unless you know the original min and max values.

Comment: I see thanks @Piglet